# SQL DB2 Accumulate Strings from multiple rows into one column

Tags: sql, string, db2, udf

I have two tables header and details.

Header: id + data example 1; Text

Details: id + description  example 1 description 1; 1 description 2

I want to select both tables with the following result:

1; description 1 description 2

My idea was using an  udf like

```
BEGIN                                                         
  DECLARE RETURNVAL VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' ;       
  FOR CSRC1 AS C1 CURSOR                                      
     FOR SELECT description
        FROM myTable WHERE ID = PARID            
  END FOR ;                                                   
  RETURN LTRIM(RETURNVAL) ;                                   
END
```

But I wonder if this could be done with pure sql which should be much faster.

//Ralf

Comment: Take a look at the LISTAGG function.

Comment: Ok, this works for DB2 V9.7 LU etc., but I forgot to say that I'm on an iseries with DB2 V7R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to use before the listagg() function became available.

```
(select substr(xmlserialize(xmlagg(xmltext(concat(', ', description))) as varchar(1024)),3) from myTable where ID = PARID) as "Concatenated Values"
```

The xml*() functions have been around much longer than listagg().  See if that works.